# Mayan-EDMS integration with user sso

Tags: keycloak, mayanedms

The Mayan-EDMS is a great project and we are looking forward to using it in our project. Our project is having lots of users already in the system, so I am looking for SSO for Mayan-EDMS. We have already seen the LDAP doc, but we looking for Keycloak.

Comment: did you manage tog this working?